# Inconsistent data of chemical potential from different papers

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, projector-augmented-wave, reproducing-data-from-papers

I am looking for chemical potential from literature.$^{1,2}$
I compared the method and data they provided. They use the Fitted Elemental Reference Energy method via GGA+U on VASP employing PAW. The U values in these papers are a little different. As far as I understand from the papers, the chemical potential is equal to total energy of an isolated atom in a box (for example, 10x10x10). Am I right? Then I think it should be similar. However, I found that the data are somehow inconsistent. For example:

| Element | Paper 2 (Table 1) | Paper 1 (Table V: Appendix) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fe | 2.200 | -6.15 |
| Mn | 1.987 | -7.00 |
| Co | 1.987 | -4.75 |

**Can anyone please explain this?**

1. Stevanović, V., Lany, S., Zhang, X., and Zunger, A. Correcting density functional theory for accurate predictions of compound enthalpies of formation: Fitted elemental-phase reference energies
   Phys. Rev. B 85, 115104 https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.85.115104
2. Kirklin, S., Saal, J., Meredig, B. et al. The Open Quantum Materials Database (OQMD): assessing the accuracy of DFT formation energies. npj Comput Mater 1, 15010 (2015). https://doi.org/10.1038/npjcompumats.2015.10

Comment: Are these papers using different codes / levels of theory?  Total energies are often arbitrary and only differences can be looked at.

Comment: I think chemical potential (reference) is not the isolated atoms in a box but from the elemental ground states, for example, metallic Fe for Fe. Note that the absolute value of chemical potential in DFT is only meaningful with respect to a particular set of pseudopotentials (just like the actual values of the energy themselves).

Comment: @TristanMaxson as I understand from these papers, they both used VASP with same method.

Comment: @bzbzbz I am still confused about "the elemental ground states". For example, Fe has 2 phases bcc and fcc. When we put several atoms together and they can interact with each others. The total energy now consists of interaction energy between atoms, then I think the obtained result is not typical for element, and it depend on different phases.

Comment: +1. Welcome to our community, and thank you for contributing your question here! We hope to see much more of you !!!

Comment: @Binh Thien yes, in theory, you are free to choose which phase to use but bear in mind that the experimental data are sometimes only available to some of the phases. The convention would be to use the one that is stable at "standard conditions".

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained why you need the chemical potentials. The chemical potential is the energy of an atom in a reference configuration, usually the elemental material (e.g. FM bcc for iron); since there is an arbitrary "zero" of energy, the absolute value of this number is meaningless, its usefulness comes from its value *relative* to that in other environments. A chemical potential computed in a plane-wave DFT package such as VASP would be expected to depend strongly on the pseudopotential and XC functional, but the relative values would be much more consistent.

Comment: @PhilHasnip In general, we can use chemical potentials to estimate the formation energy. But yes, there are some problems so that we might not get accurate formation energy. The authors in these papers tried to fit chemical potentials and then they might obtain better results. But I think their data are not consistent even though they use the same method. Please check these attached papers for more details.

Comment: Chemical potential is coming from free energy, not energy or formation energy, therefore I can imagine there can be differences in e.g. how vibrational entropy is estimated and other details.

Comment: BinhThien was the comment by @Greg helpful? Since it has now been more than a year since you asked this question, is here any update you can give us?

Comment: I was also searching about chemical potential . I think the data mentioned in the paper titled "https://www.nature.com/articles/npjcompumats201510" is more useful and matches the chemical potentials used in the literature for other materials. Here I am attaching one more reference here:
https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.4934935